# Smooth dynamic count-up animation

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to create a smooth count-up animation in React. The goal is to have it take the same amount of time each time but the value can be anywhere from 1-5000.

I've made the countup work using setInterval and setting the delay differently depending on the value to be counted. This works but the timing isn't consistent.

I know that there is a package for this but I'm hoping not to add to the list of single use packages in our app.

Does anyone have any suggestions for a solution? Maybe using scss and the data-attribute?

Comment: What’s the package that you’re referring to? Have you had a look at the GitHub src code to see if there’s something you could adapt from there?

Comment: I was thinking about react-countup. I used it while testing but the company wants to keep packages to a minimum. I ended up creating a custom hook that did pretty much the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I found this great article about how to do it in react. I used the core of that to create a custom hook. Works very well but would still like to make it work using sass since the underlying page sometimes makes the animation choke since it's poorly optimized.

Here is the article:
[A simple countup animation](https://jshakespeare.com/simple-count-up-number-animation-javascript-react/)

//What I ended up doing

```
const easeOutQuad = (t) => t * (2 - t);
const frameDuration = 1000 / 60;

function useCountUp({ endValue, duration = 1000, onComplete }) {
  const countTo = parseInt(endValue, 10);
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [start, setStart] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!start) {
      return;
    }
    let frame = 0;
    const totalFrames = Math.round(duration / frameDuration);
    const counter = setInterval(() => {
      frame++;
      const progress = easeOutQuad(frame / totalFrames);
      setCount(Math.floor(countTo * progress));

      if (frame === totalFrames) {
        if (onComplete) {
          //Trigger passed in function
          onComplete();
        }
        clearInterval(counter);
      }
    }, frameDuration);
  }, [start]);

  return { count, setStart };
}
```